# Determine if display_field is request from {safecracker} tag vs. backend?

Tags: safecracker, add-on-development, fieldtype

:)

I am trying to develop a new fieldtype and would like to display different markup depending on whether the field was requested by the user or in the backend.

Is there a reliable way to detect in the display_field() function whether it was requested via the {exp:safecracker} {custom_fields} loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for the presence of the Safecracker library:

```
if (isset(ee()->safecracker))
```

Or check if you're in the control panel

```
if (REQ === 'CP')
```

Comment: That's what I do too. Use `if(isset($this->EE->safecracker))` for versions prior to EE 2.6 though. ;)

Comment: Thanks very much gents. Just got around to it and it works brilliant. :)